# is schema mandatory for spark structured streaming processing Json record

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I was going through the spark structured streaming in the below blog.

[Structured Streaming](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/01/19/real-time-streaming-etl-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html)

he is first creating schema variable using below piece of code.

```
val cloudTrailSchema = new StructType()
  .add("Records", ArrayType(new StructType()
    .add("additionalEventData", StringType)
    .add("apiVersion", StringType)
    .add("awsRegion", StringType)
```

Then below is the actual spark code

```
val rawRecords = spark.readStream
  .schema(cloudTrailSchema)
  .json("s3n://mybucket/AWSLogs/*/CloudTrail/*/2017/*/*")
```

As json record will have schema by default, Why should we provide the schema.  For example in spark batch streaming we dont provide any schema in below line of code.

```
val peopleDF = spark.read.json(path)
```

The code infers the schema of Dataframe directly from Json record.

So can we process json records in spark structured streaming without using schema ?

Answer (score 1):

Schema is required by default, but you can use schema inference by setting spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference to true

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference=true")
```

More info here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#schema-inference-and-partition-of-streaming-dataframesdatasets

> By default, Structured Streaming from file based sources requires you to specify the schema, rather than rely on Spark to infer it automatically. This restriction ensures a consistent schema will be used for the streaming query, even in the case of failures. For ad-hoc use cases, you can reenable schema inference by setting spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference to true.

Answer (score 0):

Schema is required.

This is easily testable. Just remove ".schema()" option when running your structured streaming query and it should fail with a message saying a schema is required.

[Schema inference and partition of streaming DataFrames/Datasets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#schema-inference-and-partition-of-streaming-dataframesdatasets)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The documentation says it is for File based sources. Will that apply to the messages being streamed from kafka also ?

Comment: The messages from Kafka will be in a specific format that is Key, Value, Topic, Partition, Offset, and timestamp. The type of the key and value can be different formats but is typically string or Avro. The data will be in the Value column and requires no schema. 

But to make that json string useful you can apply a schema using the "from_json()" function.

Comment: Check out the
[Kafka integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html). Hope that helps